# moving dots in scala

Tags: swing, scala, actor

I am writing a simple population model in scala.  I want to model each species with a different colored dot and output (in the gui...I'm using scala swing) a continuous display of each instances position.  The animals are free to move and can multiply, eat each other, etc.

How exactly do I output this continuous display?  I can do buttons and layouts in swing but this idea of a continuous display screen is foreign to me

Comment: You might like to play around with the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976788/scala-easiest-2d-graphics-for-simply-writing-a-2d-array-to-the-screen/6978542#6978542 Jonas is right: essentially all you need to do is to override `paintComponent`

Comment: For timer examples you might like to check out: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Image_noise#Scala. I aslo have a blog post on wrapping the Swing timer: tl;dr version - see solution 2 postscript  http://www.luigip.com/?p=48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom component by extending `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` where you implement the drawing of your colored dots.

See [Trail: 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and [Lesson: Getting Started with Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/index.html) for more information about Java 2D graphics API.

To continuosly update the panel, you can use a **[Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)** to update it in intervals:

> To perform a task repeatedly.
>   For example, you might perform animation or update a component that displays progress toward a goal.